# Modify date objects in array from jquery.getJSON using cordova.globalization.stringToDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have the cordova plugin globalization and I wish to use the .dateToString to alter dateTimes that are in the JSON objects

```
incoming JSON = [{"alphaID":"JV033","status":"open","dateadded":1433531166},{"alphaID":"JV032","status":"on hold","dateadded":1433530583}]
```

so this is my code

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", getJSONList, false);
var dateToDisplay = ''

function getJSONList() {
    $.getJSON("https://myserver.com/ajax_calls/list_sr_app.asp", function(e) {
        e.forEach(function(arrayItem, index, thearray) {
            var x = arrayItem.dateadded * 1000; //alert(new Date(x)); this works (un-adjusted dates of course)
            //alert(displayDate(x)); this does NOT work - delivers undefined
            thearray[index].arrayItem.dateadded = displayDate(x) // the assigment of the return of displayDate(x) does not work either
        });
        constructJSONList(e); //this function (not here) works
    });
} // end of getJSONList()


function displayDate(d) { 
    navigator.globalization.dateToString(
        new Date(d), 
        function(date) {
            dateToDisplay = date.value; /* alert(dateToDisplay); - this alert works*/
        },
        function() {
            dateToDisplay = 'Error getting dateString'
        }, {
            formatLength: 'short',
            selector: 'date and time'
        }
    );
    return dateToDisplay;
}
```

There are two issues:

1. As soon as I try to use the date.value outside of the results function, even in a variable, it becomes "undefined", so return dateToDisplay; does not actually work. When calling the function like `alert(displayDate(1433531166000));` the result in the alert box is "undefined" unless that call is from within the function (as is commented out above)
2. How can I replace the object's parameter "dateadded" with a new value - at the moment I can't make any changes at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the event listener for 'device ready' but it looks as if your calls to get the json (and display the date) aren't being done before the device is actually ready. Cordova functions won't run (won't be defined) until the device is ready.
Try this event listener:

```
document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );
function onDeviceReady() {                
    // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
    getJSONList();
};
```

This works for me, anyway, and the debugger gives me 'undefined' for 'globalization' if I do the event listener the way you have done.

Comment: Thanks @quilkin, the globalization is available because I can get an alert from the alert(dateToDisplay); from inside the dateToDisplay() for each iteration of the loop. Actually my problem seems to be that I can't access date.value from outside that function. I have solved the assignment to the object property with:
    e.forEach( function (sr, i, rete)
    {
     var x = e[i].dateadded * 1000;
     e[i].dateadded = x;

    });
it was just a matter of accessing the right parts of the object